# Crash in unarchiveObjectWithFile under specific conditions

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, exception, plist

I have the following code to read an archived array:

```
id temp = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
if(temp && [temp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
   self.posts      = [temp mutableCopy];
}
```

the following code is to save the array

```
-(void)savePostList
{
    NSURL *tempURL = [[[ZZAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] applicationCacheDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"postCache.plist"];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.posts 
                                toFile:[tempURL path]];
}
```

Generally everything works perfectly, however in very particular (currently undetermined) circumstances the app starts crashing at startup with an exception:

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x275900
```

the crash actually happens inside of the call to:

```
id temp = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

Having pulled out the plist from the device it looks very odd (and very empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array/>
</plist>
```

If I wrap the whole thing in a @try / @catch clause then 'everything is fine' as so:

```
        @try {
            id temp = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
            if(temp && [temp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            {
                self.posts      = [temp mutableCopy];
                if(self.posts)
                {
                    [self precacheImages];
                }
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            // exception thrown - delete file
            NSLog(@"An exception occurred reading file - deleting");
            NSError * err;

            if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&err])
            {
                NSLog(@"Error deleting file: %@", err);
            }
        }
```

My question is: does anyone have any idea what would cause this (as in the .plist is 'empty') and then for the unarchiveObjectWithFile call to cause an exception the way it does (which according to a stack trace is inside of the system library).

Answer (score 0):

you will want to something more like this to deserialize the plist

```
NSArray * someArray = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList: [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:nil];
```

Comment: Nah that section of code had not even been reached - as I said the exception was thrown *inside* the unarchiveObjectWithFile call.

Comment: oh yeah that is wrong, you shouldn't be using a keyed archiver to deserialize a plist... editing

Comment: The archive/unarchive is correct as I am using non-property list safe objects which support NSCoding. The questions is not 'how to do it' as I've done it plenty of times before. The root of the question is how did the encoded data get so messed up as to cause the unarchiveObjectWithFile to crash. I've submitted a bug report with apple now including the file which caused it to crash.

Comment: then why don't you print out the exception, it could be an exception in your model object

Comment: This method raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if the file at path does not contain a valid archive... I assume that is what is being thrown, which would make some sense as there are no key value pairs in the plist...

Comment: the documentation doesn't of course specify what is a valid archive.

Comment: I did specify the exception: -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance …..

Comment: yeah, you are right... apparently you just can used a keyed unarchiver to unarchive an array... you can use an NSUnarchiver